# Example of inaccessible website

Tags: accessibility

Please share any website which is inaccessible so I can test the accessibility of that website and identify defects.
I have tested already these two sites
https://www.washington.edu/accesscomputing/AU/before.html

https://www.w3.org/WAI/demos/bad/after/news.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.washington.edu/accesscomputing/AU/, is a great example to demonstrate accessibility issues and the impact of accessibility improvements. It showcases the "Before" and "After" versions of the website, highlighting the changes made to enhance accessibility.

Before (Before: https://www.washington.edu/accesscomputing/AU/before.html):

- The "Before" version of the website may have various accessibility issues that can pose challenges for individuals with disabilities.
- These issues could include lack of alternative text for images, improper heading structure, insufficient color contrast, inaccessible forms, or navigation difficulties.
- Users with visual impairments, hearing impairments, motor disabilities, or cognitive disabilities may face difficulties accessing and navigating the content effectively.

After (After: https://www.washington.edu/accesscomputing/AU/after.html):

- The "After" version of the website represents the accessibility improvements made to address the issues found in the "Before" version.
- Accessibility enhancements could involve adding alternative text to images, restructuring headings for better organization, improving color contrast for readability, providing proper form labels and instructions, and implementing other accessibility best practices.
- These improvements aim to ensure that users with disabilities can access and interact with the website's content more easily and effectively.
- By comparing the "Before" and "After" versions, you can visually see the impact of accessibility improvements and how they positively influence the user experience for individuals with disabilities.

Here are a few more example links that demonstrate accessibility issues and improvements:

1. https://www.w3.org/WAI/demos/bad/before/ (Before) and https://www.w3.org/WAI/demos/bad/after/ (After) - A demonstration by W3C showcasing accessibility issues and their resolutions.
2. https://www.mass.gov/ - The official website of the Massachusetts government, known for its efforts to improve accessibility but still facing ongoing challenges.
3. https://www.apple.com/ - The Apple website, often considered an example of good accessibility practices but may still have minor accessibility issues.

Please note that these examples are for educational and demonstration purposes, and the accessibility status of these websites may change over time.

When evaluating accessibility, it's essential to consider various disabilities, including visual, auditory, motor, and cognitive impairments. Accessibility guidelines such as the Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) can provide detailed information on accessibility requirements and best practices.

I hope these examples and explanations help in understanding accessibility issues and improvements. If you have any further questions or require additional assistance, please feel free to ask.